# Converting byte array to decimal

Tags: perl

Was wondering if someone could explain this snippet to me in depth

```
(my $bytearray_val_ascii = $in) =~ s/([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/chr(hex $1)/eg;
```

Comment: Simpler: `my $bytearray_val_ascii = pack( "H*", $in );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `s///` is a regex [substitution operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer) which the `=~` operator [binds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) to a variable on its left-hand side, so a statement

```
$var =~ s/pattern/replacement/;
```

matches the *pattern* in the variable `$var` and performs a substitution of it by the *replacement* string, evaluated in a double-quoted context. The operation can be  tuned and tweaked by [modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) that follow the closing delimiter (and which can also be embedded in the pattern).<sup>†</sup>

This changes the variable "in-place" -- after this statement `$var` is changed.  An idiom to preserve `$var` and store the changed string in another variable is to assign `$var` to that other variable and "then" change it (by ordering operations by parenthesis), all in one statement.  And the commonly used idiom is to also introduce a new variable in that statement

```
(my $new_var = $original) =~ s/.../.../;
```

Now `$original` is unchanged, while the changed string is in `$new_var` (if the *pattern* matched).

This idiom is nowadays unneeded since a `r` (non-destructive) modifier was introduced [in 5.14](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta#Non-destructive-substitution)

```
my $new_var = $original =~ s/.../.../r;
```

The `$original` is unchanged and the changed string returned, then assigned to `$new_var`.

---

The regex itself matches and captures two consecutive alphanumeric characters, runs `hex` on them and then `chr` on what `hex` returns, and uses that result to replace them. It keeps going through the string to do that with all such pairs that it finds.

If this is indeed precisely all that there is to do then it is more simply done using [pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack)

```
my $bytearray_val_ascii = pack( "H*", $in );
```

---

<sup>†</sup>
Here the modifiers are: `e`, which makes is so that the replacement side is evaluated as code so that what that code evaluates to is used for replacement; and `g` which makes it continue searching and replacing through the whole string (not just the first occurrence of `pattern` that is found).